# Update my remote MySQL database with my local MySQL database

Tags: mysql, perl, wamp

I have a local Perl script that does a lot of parsing of web pages and then successfully updates my **local** MySQL database (WAMP server). I now want to send this local data to my **remote** server, but **remotely connecting to my database isn't allowed** with my hosting company. Unfortunately I never thought of that problem.

So, I now need to find an automated way to update my remote server (every 15mins). I mistakenly thought I could just edit my Perl script with the details of the remote server.

I am aware that I could use CGI or PHP to do the parsing on the server, but I really want to keep the parsing local for now.

**Summary:**
Local MySQL database -> remote MySQL database every 15mins ??

Any ideas what I can do?

Thanks :-)

Comment: There's a lot of stuff mentioned that I have no experience with :-) so I'm going to have to do a bit of research on the methods already mentioned before I can vote the accepted answer.
I also need to ask my hosting company a few questions as well (SSH, etc).
Thanks for the helpful replies, please feel free to comment on the current answers to help me decide which is the best/easiest option.

Comment: If you can't make a remote connection to your DB and you can't SSH to your machine, then you can't do this. Also, you don't need to run your script as a CGI on the remote to do that same thing if they allow you to have cron jobs. But overall it sounds like you need to get a better hosting provider. I'd suggest something like Linode where you get a full machine with full access. Sure you'll have to learn a bit of sys-admin skills, but it'll definitely pay off in the long run.

Comment: At least I now know that I have to explore other options. The idea of using a VPS is interesting, it seems like a good way to solve my pronlem. Thanks.

Comment: +1 a VPS will provide you more flexibility and bypass all the limits you're facing with your current hosting. Simple web hosting are great for simple websites, as soon as it gets a little more complex VPS should be the next step. Linode is great but if you're looking for something cheaper to start have a look to this site http://www.lowendbox.com/

Comment: I'll have a look at that site, thanks. This is all becoming a lot of work :-) I wasn't planning on using a VPS so soon, but if it means I can remotely connect to the server then I guess it will be worth it. I just hope the learning curve isn't too steep because I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

if replication is not an option but you can still establish an ssh connection from local box to remote box, then

1. run mysqldump to export data into a file http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where
2. scp file to remote box
3. `mysql -u username -p password database_name < dumpfile.sql`

Comment: SSH isn't allowed on my remote server.

Answer (score 1):

If your server does not accept connections to mysql remotely you can create a ssh tunnel. Then you can apply the replication solution proposed by matcheek.

Here is a hint: http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html

Comment: I use this solution on Windows via putty to connect to remote DBs with HeidiSQL. It works great, but I do not recommend it for automated transfers.

Comment: SSH isn't allowed on my remote server.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the responses I've received, I think the answer to my original question is to stop using a cheap shared hosting company (no remote access to server, no cron jobs, etc) and start using a VPS hosting company. That will give me the freedom to remotely connect to my server, etc.
Thanks again to those who replied.

Answer (score 0):

From how you described the problem replication seems to be the way to go
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/replication-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

Using a cron job could be another option. It would read file from your local machine and import data in the remote box.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the follwing:

- On every **local** run, write the SQL statements (sans `SELECT`),
  that you run against your copy of the DB also into a file
- On your WAMP server create a small PHP script, gives back the oldest script from the first step (soem auth ofcourse)
- On your remote server run a cronjob, that gets this from your local server and runs the SQL against the DB, then acknowledges it
- On acknowledgement on your WAMP server, drop the file and give back the next one.

While this seems complicated, it allows for a restart after connectivity loss - something that I consider imposrtant.